# How to prevent editing of files (renaming,sharing etc) while selecting files from a document picker in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have implemented a document picker and want to avoid the editing of files & folder (like the option to rename,copy,share etc ) while I browse through the document picker. Can anyone please help me since there is nothing like allowsEditing for UIDocumentPickerViewController.

```
func documentPicker(from view: UIView) {

   let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF),
   String(kUTTypeJPEG), String(kUTTypeGIF)], in: .import)

   importMenu.delegate = self
   importMenu.setEditing(false, animated: false)
   importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

   if let presentation = importMenu.popoverPresentationController {
       presentation.permittedArrowDirections = .any
       presentation.sourceView = view
       presentation.sourceRect = view.bounds
   }

   parentController?.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried.